# String[] taking null values

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file that needs to be encrypted. The entire text is broken down into chucks of 6 characters. From the text that I have taken, after dividing into blocks of 6 characters, I get 45 groups, each group of 6 characters.

I am taking one group at a time and performing the encryption process.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < group; i++) {
        s[i] = input.substring(j, j + block_size);
        ASCIIMatrx asc = new ASCIIMatrx();
        asc.text(s, k1, a1, b1, n);
        j += block_size;
    }
```

For the first iteration it takes the first six characters, but for the rest it takes null values. I have no idea where am I missing.

`ASCIIMatrx` is a method to which I pass the sub string along with the keys required for encryption.

Comment: It's probably because it's initialized with bigger size than you actually fill it, use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Start debugging: what's the value of `input`? What's the value of the `substring`? What's `j`? Use log statements or the debugger.

Comment: Where do I use ArrayList ? I am not clear with that.

Comment: You're likely wasting space (using an array with more space than you need). I'd opt for a List instead, ArrayList maybe.

Comment: @Jil It's a list, as opposed to a "fixed"-sized array.

Comment: @DaveNewton I did debug. Input is a text that is read from a text file. At first j = 0, then j value increases to 6. The value of i in the for loop is not being incremented to 1.

Comment: I would start with printing the results of `input.substring(j, j + block_size)` do you get the results that you expect?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I will try with ArrayList. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin I was able to print the sub string .

Comment: @Jil Then `group` is not what you think it is. Figure out why not. We can't; you don't give enough info to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For references, the default value is `null`. I think you're allocating more elements than you actually need in the array, it'll be filled with `null` values. See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For all reference types ([§4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is `null`

Instead of having a fixed size array, use an `ArrayList` instead:

```
ArrayList<MyType> arr = new ArrayList<>();
...
arr.add(myType);
```

<sup>Note that the diamond operator is available since Java 7, if you're using older version, you should 
`ArrayList<MyType> arr = new ArrayList<MyType>();`</sup>

Comment: Ain't able to figure out working with lists.. grrr !!